# el bucle for i in , no reconoce el valor "www"

Tags: python, bucle-for

tengo un pequeño problema , soy nuevo en programacion, el error es el siguente:

- NO ME RECONOCE EL VALOR ASIGNADO PARA QUE CUMPLA LA CONDICION if i == "WWW" , LO TOMA COMO SI FUERA FALSO, PERO ESCRIBI WWW.GOOGLE.COM

```py
web = False
    
website = str(input("Escriba la direccion web: "))
    
for i in website:
    if i == "www":
        web = True
    
if web == True:
    print("La direccion de la pagina web es correcta: ")
    
else:
    print("es incorrecta la direccion web")
```

Comment: Primero que nada, el codigo va como texto, no como imagenes. Segundo, que tratas de hacer ??

Comment: estaba practicando , como verficiar si una url es correcta , si lleva www o .com , es correcta , si no llega eso , no es correcta , aqui te dejo el codigo :

Answer (score 0):

```
web = False
```

por ahora está demás

```
website = input("direccion: ") #input devuelve una cadena str es innecesario

for i in website:
    print(i)
```

¿para que hice eso? si lo ejecutas verás que devuelve cada carácter de la cadena

```
if "www." in website:
    print("correto")
else:
    print("incorrecto")
```

cuando es una cadena con in verificas si una subcadena está incluida en la cadena

otra cosa, así como está, todavía es engañoso porque  si cualquierawww. dará correcto, lo mejor sería:

```
if "www." in website[:4]:
    print("correto")
else:
    print("incorrecto")
```

así comparas los primeros caracteres de la cadena pero, también está incompleto ya que www. solo no es una dirección válida, esto es solo para que veas como funciona python

Agregado en edición:

una cadena tiene caracteres y cada uno ocupa una posición numérica, ej "casa" la c es la posición 0, la a =1 ,la s = 2 y así sucesivamente cuando usas [:4] le decís a python que tome un "pedazo" de la cadena hasta el lugar 4, si usas [1:5] es desde el lugar 1 al 5 , te recomiendo que leas slice, en python y que pruebes con :

```
cadena="esta es una cadena de prueba"
print(cadena[4:8])
```

cambia los índices y ve el resultado.

Comment: gracias ! como hago para copiar el codigo como tu lo has hecho y no se deforme al pegarlo  y que salga con color?

Comment: hay un tag {} en el editor cuando haces la respuesta o pregunta,  simplemente selecciona el código y haces click ahí

Comment: @MiguelAngel Copia y pegado en tu editor y luego solo lo intentas bien

Comment: esta bien muchas gracias Christian

Comment: que significa [:4] y como se usa ? y como haria para agregarle .com , tambien para que lo verifique

Comment: @MiguelAngel te mostré lo básico, ahora intenta algo vos y si no anda, publica la duda

Comment: También tienes el método `startswith`

Comment: @CandidMoe es cierto hay muchas formas, me límite a lo que él intenta hacer en su evidente inicio.

Comment: @MiguelAngel [:4] significa los primeros 4 caracteres, en este caso de `website`

Comment: gracias a todos ! lo tendré en cuenta